# How to create and use classes/objects in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion

I cant find any simple examples on how to write a very simple class or model and use it, in cfscript.

Here is what I want, in php:
oocaller.php:

```
<?php
include 'oo-model.php';
$dog = new animal('dog');
echo $dog->says();
```

oo-model:

```
<?php    
class animal{
    public $type;

    function __construct($type){
        $this->type =$type;
    }

    function says(){
        if($this->type == 'dog')
            return 'woof!';
        if($this->type == 'cat')
            return 'meow!';         
        return 'I dont know what to say!';
    }   
}
```

ok this works...

oocaller.cfm:

```
   <cfscript>
//include 'oomodel.cfc'; //dont need, autoincluded
//obj = new admin.d.oomodel(); //for path, use dots not slashes...
//obj = CreateObject("component", "oomodel");        
obj = CreateObject("component", "/admin/d/oomodel");//either works        
obj.out();  
writeoutput('<HR>'); 
writedump(obj.other); 
writeoutput('<HR>'); 
writedump(obj); 
</cfscript>
```

with: oomodel.cfc:

```
 component  { 
    thevar = 'thevrrrrr';
    this.other = 'otherrrr';
    public function out(){
        writeoutput(variables.thevar & "<BR>");
        writeoutput(thevar          & "<BR>");
        writeoutput(this.other      & "<BR>");
    }
}
```

Comment: A component must be a self-contained "class", with nothing following the closing curly brace. You then instantiate the component as an object in a separate file (either a cfm template or within another component).  Also, if you move your code outside the component block to a separate file, you can eliminate the <cfscript> tags, as components can be written entirety in script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save the following to `d.cfc`

```
component displayname="d" output="false" { 
    public function out(){
        writeoutput('blahblahblah');
    }
}
```

save the following to a `test.cfm`

```
<cfscript>
obj = new d();    
obj.out();    
</cfscript>
```

As for `this`, it is a scope that carries all the public methods and properties.  Usually you do not need to specify the scope for private vars, but if you want to be explicit, safe, and get the last little bit of performance, you should use `variables.theVar`.  `Varibales` is the scope that carries all the private methods and properties.

To write the proper constructor, please use an `init()` function.

Looks like you just started with ColdFusion, may I suggest:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/topics.html
- http://www.learncfinaweek.com/

Comment: Ok, displayname is superflous, then?  The name of the class is the name of the file?  Also, apparantly, it will auto-load the class, without includ()ing it.  Also: `new d()`  is exactly the same as `CreateObject("component", "d"); ` ?

Comment: Yes, `new d()` is equivalent to `createObject('component', 'd';`. While you aren't "importing" the classes, your `new` declaration is a path to the class. In the above example, it assumes that either `d` is in the root folder, or in the same folder as the code calling `new d()`. You can specify a relative path by doing ` obj = new path.to.d();` where `d.cfc` is in the folder `path/to`.

Comment: Please see revised question...  I got the calling/cfc part figured out, but not the 'this'

Comment: @DougCassidy please ask another question next time.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it, now.  See above.